# C++ Constructor Return Embedded system

Tags: c++, constructor, null

I'm developing a C++ test program. The environment doesn't offer exceptions support and I need to know if there is enough space when using `new`. I've seen posts about it using the `new(std::nothrow)`, but I would like to ask you the following:

Imagine that we have a piece of code that calls `new (std::nothrow)` and it turns out that it can allocate the object and calls the constructor, but within the constructor there is another `new` which can not be allocated.

How can I possibly know if the object has been initialized properly or not?(Please don't answer something like a flag to check before calling the instance) 
Is there anyway to return `NULL` from the constructor?

Comment: If possible, pass your pointer to your class to avoid allocation.

Comment: "The environment doesn't offer exceptions support" It's not really C++ then.

Comment: @n.m. yes it is, you can do C++ without exception and still having features like RAII. Exceptions are an aspect of C++ but not the most defining.

Comment: @nefas I'm not aware of any authoritative source that publishes a list of defining C++ features ordered by degree of their importance.

Comment: more defining in the sense that: it's something that make C++ different from the other language, if you remove it you don't write (good) C++ any more. You can write C++ without exception (there is a lot of reason to do it: platform that doesn't support exceptions, ...) but if you stop using RAAi, you might as well choose an other language.

Comment: @nefas what's RAAi? If you mean RAII, is not a separate language feature. It's an idiom supported by several language mechanisms, exceptions among them.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot return a value from a constructor.

Throwing an exception is the only sane way to signal a constructor failure. If exceptions are not available, the best course of action would be to avoid altogether constructors that can possibly fail. Move all non-trivial initialisations to a dedicated `Init` member function.

Note this means no copying of anything that allocates resources. Disable all copy constructors and copy assignment operators in such classes.

Comment: Thanks, I knew you can not but I asked if someone figured out a way of doing it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you have to give your class some kind of `bool is_valid()` member and call it after constructing.

And maybe reconsider if u really need dynamic memory when constructing the object. Maybe just simplify constructor and give your class some kind of `bool initialize()`

> Please don't answer smth like a flag to check before calling the instance

Sorry, did read that too late. But you're asking for a return value from a constructor. Which u know is not possible...

Well there is an alternative to flags and error codes:
`std::exit, std::abort, std::terminate` but i guess u don't want this either.

I also forgot `assert()`, which also doesn't 'return' anything

Comment: Thanks for the answer but none of those are valid ones. I need the code to execute even if there is memory or not.

Comment: @VicenteArnauMorales: If your code can execute without memory, why are you even trying to allocate memory? And why are you treating a lack of memory as an error? I don't believe your comment here. Out of memory is a run-time error, and you don't need your code to execute in that situation. Alternatively, you're working on a [life|safety|mission]-critical system, and then you allocate all objects statically (at compile time). If it compiles, you have memory, if not, you redesign the software (and possibly the requirements) until it compiles.

Comment: My comment was not right. I meant that the program should keeps running. Check the comment I wrote on Walter's answer. Sorry for this

Answer (score 0):

*I need the code to execute even if there is memory or not.* So what do you want the constructor to do if there is no memory? You can change your class to always construct into a valid state, even if this is not the type of state you finally want.

```
struct foo
{
  size_t size=0;     // default state is empty
  bar*data=nullptr;  // default state has no data allocated

  int resize(size_t new_size)
  {
    if(new_size == size) return 0;
    delete[] data;
    data = new bar[new_size];
    size = data? new_size : 0;
    return data? 0 : error_code;
  }
};
```

Note the implicit default constructor.

Comment: With that I meant that I need that the porgram keeps running. The constructor can fail and the component of the program that use it is not gonna work, but the program should run